# How to show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{x+it-2}dt\right)=\frac{1}{x+iy-2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm trying to show that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{x+it-2}dt\right)=\frac{1}{x+iy-2}$$ In an area that doesn't contain the point $2+0i$. If the function under the integral was a real function then it would have been immediate from the Fundamental Theorem but I haven't studied of an equivalent result for a complex function. I need to somehow show this result through a direct computation of some sort.

Edit: I would prefer not to use complex logarithms since I'm not really familiar with the subject but I do know it differs quite a bit from the real logarithm.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since a complex-valued function is of the form $f = g+ih$ with $g$ and $h$ real, it is exactly the same. You apply the (real) fundamental theorem to the real and the imaginary part.

Comment: There was a small mistake with the equation, I corrected it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Daniel's comment I realized that it's completely unnecessary to try and explicitly calculate the real/imaginary parts of $\frac{1}{x+it-2}$ and the result follows immediately from the following equalities: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{x+it-2}dt\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\int_{0}^{y}\mathfrak{R}\left(\frac{1}{x+it-2}\right)dt+i\int_{0}^{y}\mathfrak{I}\left(\frac{1}{x+it-2}\right)dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_{0}^{y}\mathfrak{R}\left(\frac{1}{x+it-2}\right)dt+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\int_{0}^{y}\mathfrak{I}\left(\frac{1}{x+it-2}\right)dt$$
$$\mathfrak{R}\left(\frac{1}{x+iy-2}\right)+i\mathfrak{I}\left(\frac{1}{x+iy-2}\right)=\frac{1}{x+iy-2}$$

Thanks for the help Daniel!